# Why am I getting this error when I click the NSButton: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

```
    - (IBAction)advanced_search_clickled:(id)sender {
    self.google.gURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@&%@", self.google.all_these_words_string, self.google.this_exact_word_or_phrase_string, self.google.any_of_these_words_string, self.google.none_of_these_words_string, self.google.num_range1_string, self.google.num_range2_string, self.google.language_string, self.google.region_string, self.google.last_update_string, self.google.site_or_domain_string, self.google.terms_appearing_string, self.google.safeSearch_string, self.google.reading_level_string, self.google.file_type_string, self.google.usage_rights_string];
}
```

I have other actions I use to assign the string values (`NSStrings`) when ever a `NSPopUpMenu` or an `NSTextField` is changed.  When I run it I can occasionally (depending on which controls I interact with) I get different code number errors instead of 1, it is sometimes 13, and on the rare occasion it does work, all the strings are `(null)`.  The same error also occurs on this when I run it: `0x7fff870cb989:  xorl   %edi, %edi`

Comment: Is it possible that the object referenced by `self` has been released and deallocated by the time this instance method is invoked?

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: @Rob Yes that was the problem (I think).  When I created the properties in the class I created all the strings, they were not strong properties.  when I changed them to from being `assigned` to `strong` the program worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoshC String properties should be `copy`.

Comment: More generally: If there is a mutable variant (e.g., NSMutableString to NSString), your property should be `copy`, so that you don't end up holding somebody else's mutable object which they may mutate while you're holding it. Otherwise, the property should usually be `strong`, unless the object owns you, in which case it should be `weak`.

Comment: Expanded Director's Cut of previous comment: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2013-07-21/how-to-decide-which-ownership-keyword-to-give-a-property

Comment: Thanks, I have not known objective-c for that long, so it has been an awkward adjustment.